# Interconversion between different representations of quantum channels

Tags: quantum-operation, kraus-representation

I was reading [TQI-notes by Watrous](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI-notes/) where they introduce different representations for quantum channels and wondering how to go from one to the other. I have:

\begin{align}
&|\Phi(\rho)\rangle\!\rangle \tag{1}
\\
&= K(\Phi)|\rho\rangle\!\rangle \tag{2}
\\
&=|\text{tr}_2[(I\otimes \rho^T) J(\Phi)]\rangle\!\rangle \tag{3}
\end{align}

where $\Phi$ is the channel,
$\rho$ is the density operator of the quantum state input into the channel,
$|\rangle\!\rangle$ represents vectorization,
$K(\Phi)$ is the normal representation of the channel
($= \sum_i A_i \otimes \bar{A}_i$ where $A_i$ are the Kraus operators),
and $J(\Phi)$ is the Choi representation ($=\sum_i |A_i\rangle\!\rangle \langle\!\langle A_i|$) of the channel.

Questions:

1. Are the equations correct?
2. Is there a more straightforward way to rewrite Eq. (3) in terms of $J(\Phi)$? Choi representation seems very convoluted so where can this be useful?
3. I have omitted the Strinespring representation as I don't have a clear intuition for it but how can it be related to Eq.(1)?

Comment: does https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5804/55 answer your question? see also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11622/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11806/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5811/55, and links therein

Comment: Thank you. These are super helpful.

Comment: The proofs on the equivalences of these representations in Watrous' book are all constructive from what I remember.